# Microsoft mvc3 or ASP.NET Web pages for a new server-side scripter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scripting

I have experience in javascript, html(Bronze certified), css(Gold certified), sql and xml(Bronze certified), and now have turned my attention towards server side scripting. I have little experience in php but have no Idea what to choose between MVC and ASP.NET Web Pages. I like all the features that ASP.NET Web Pages(Since I already new a little about server side scripting, so getting started was not that difficult and I know a few basic things.) have like, automatic form authentication among others but I seriously doubt that it can never be by-passed. Still, for safety I use my own algorithms against sql-injection and javascript codes. But, now I am confused what to learn, MVC or ASP.NET Web Pages. All the posts I searched on internet where for new programmers. Since I am not new they are no use to me. So what should I learn MVC OR ASP.NET Web Pages and why?

*English is not my native language, there may be some grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are kind of asking what's the better option, apples or bananas. MVC is a pattern and allows you greater control over what HTML is sent to the browser whereas Web Forms has a great number of pre-made controls that do all the hard work rendering out html to the browser (but often less control of how it is rendered out)

It's also down to preferences, I personally prefer MVC as the unit testing and component nature of it give me great flexibility.  Alternatively, using WebForms you can create some things quickly using drag and drop controls.

Hope that gives you a bit of useful info.  I'd recommend reading up about both, and seeing which fits into your style of programming and go from there, but there's nothing stopping you learning and using both (just don't use them in the same project, lol)

Comment: Yeah! That would be better if I read about both, would only help me, no losses.

Comment: These links are a good place to get some basics and tutorials from both Microsoft and the community - Webforms -> http://www.asp.net/web-forms & MVC -> http://www.asp.net/mvc  (also to note, there are currently 3 versions of MVC)

Comment: Next to the answer (where it has the number) there should be a tick mark, click that to accept.